# codeigniter popup

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, popup

code in the view page

href="#" class="popup">Vehicle Details

js file for popup
(http://preview.hertzci.com/js/core.js)

var popups = function(){

```
   $$('a.popup').each(function(el){

           el.addEvent('click', function(e){

                   var href = el.href.toString();
                   href += href.contains("?") ? '&ajax' : '?ajax';
                   if ($('popup')){
                           $('popup').destroy();
                   }
                   var popup = new Element('div', {'id': 'popup'});
                   var popupInner = new Element('div', {'id': 'popupInner'}).inject(popup);
                   var closeBtn = new Element('a', {'id': 'closeBtn', 'style': 'cursor: pointer'}).inject(popup, 'top');
                   var myFx = new Fx.Morph(popup, {'duration': 600});
                   if (el.rel){
                           rel = el.rel.toString();
                           xPos = rel.split(",")[0];
                           yPos = rel.split(",")[1];
                           myFx.set({'left': xPos, 'top': yPos});
                   }
                   myFx.set({'opacity': 0});
                   closeBtn.addEvent('click', function(e){
                           myFx.start({'opacity': 0});
                           var e = new Event(e).stop();
                   });
                   popup.inject(el.getParent());
                   // Fetch popup content
                   var req = new Request.HTML({
                           method: 'get',
                           url: href,
                           data: {},
                           update: $('popupInner'),
                           onComplete: function(response) {
                                   myFx.start({'opacity': 1});
                           }
                   }).send();
                   var e = new Event(e).stop();
           });
   });
```

}

i have to view the content of "popupVehicle.php" in popup
how can i?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

In your controller file (note `TRUE`, it's the key of the approach):

```
$content = array();
$content['popup_content'] = $this->load->view('popupVehicle',array(), TRUE);
$this->load->view(*your view*, $content);
```

In your view file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /*Place your popup-showing logic here
      you need to show $('#popup') element*/
</script>
<div id='popup'><? echo $popup_content?></div>
```

The idea behind this is to load view's content into a variable, pass this variable to other view and display it in your popup element.